# Slack API: Requesting channels:read and identity scopes with one authorization

Tags: slack-api

When requesting scopes for both `channels:read` and `identity.basic` I get the following error:

> Invalid permissions requested
>   Cannot request both identity scopes and other scopes at the same time

What's the solution for this? I'm interested in identifying if a user is an administrator and listing his channels. I'm requesting the `identity.basic` scope above as it's a prerequisite for the `users:read` scope. Do I really need to get the user to click "Authorize" twice for such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You do not to authorize twice. If you need additional scopes - because you want to access the API methods - you need to use the [Add to Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) OAuth flow instead. That one will give you access to all scopes.

The [Sign-in-with Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack) OAuth flow is meant for quick user authentications only and does therefore not include any scopes that would require the user to confirm them (like `users.read`). So you can only user identity.* scopes for this flow as clearly stated in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack#button_setup) under **Valid parameters** / `scope`.